# How to implement common layouts instead of misusing tabular environments?

Tags: lists, environments, best-practices

**Note:** My hope is that this can become a general resource for "use a list instead" comments. If you have suggestions for improvement, please let me know.

---

I often see comments such as

> This layout should be typeset using a list, not a `tabular`.

and (my favorite, paraphrasing because I cannot find the exact quotation right now)

> If every `tabularx` with an `lX` preamble was a list instead, the world would be a better place.

This is all well and good, and I can see the benefits (chiefly: page breaking mid-"row" and without specialty table packages).

A `description` environment gets close, but it has a fixed left indent that does not depend on the longest item name.

The [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130099/21344) at [Automatically set description list `labelwidth` based on widest label?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130097/21344) shows a way to do this using the `environ` and `enumitem` packages.

---

**What other methods do you use to achieve this layout?** I'd like to avoid manually specifying the longest label (its width, essentially). This is something that `tabularx` does not require, and I don't want it to be required in the solution to this problem either, if I can avoid it.

---

**Alternatively, what other layouts are recommended for this type of content?** Examples of common document elements for which `tabularx` is used include nomenclature lists and other lists of notation.

---

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for blind texts
\newenvironment{mylist} % what else goes here?
  {\trivlist}
  {\endtrivlist}

\begin{document}

\section{trivlist version}
\begin{mylist}
  \item[Text 2] \lipsum*[2]
\end{mylist}

\section{tabularx version}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lX@{}}
  Text 2 & \lipsum*[2]
\end{tabularx}

\section{description version}
\begin{description}
  \item[Text 2] \lipsum*[2]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for something like `labeling` from KOMA-script `scrextend`)? Please see also [Make the lines of a description item line up](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155432)

Comment: @Johannes_B that gives the layout that I want, but it requires separate entry of the longest label, something that `tabularx` does not require and that I wish to avoid.

Comment: Gonzalo Medina's answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230537/creating-a-new-list-environment-how-to-change-the-length-of-items/230542#230542

Comment: Is it perhaps something like this what you need? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130099/3954

Comment: @GonzaloMedina yes, that's basically it. Sorry I did not find the solution in my searching.

Comment: @touhami thanks, that's basically it too, but Gonzalo's other comment leads to a more generic solution.

Comment: The standard `description` seems good to me, provided items are not too long. Long items cry for sectional divisions. Wide indentation leaves too big white areas.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137349/how-do-i-stop-a-table-where-the-margin-falls-rather-than-using-the-textwidth-co/137439#137439

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this doesn't have anything to do with _nested_ `tabularx`. ;-) And indeed, how to achieve the layout with a simple list is what I'm asking here. But I'm starting to realize that it's not just the choice of implementation that you and others are complaining about... c.f. discussion in the chat.

Comment: @PaulGessler yes I was actually looking for a different answer where I took and OPs extended tabular example and re-coded it as a list, can't find it just now:-)

Comment: @Werner I had deleted the question after seeing this. But barbara requested that it be re-opened and broadened so she could show her solution. I'd still like to see other methods. I'd hoped that this question could become a bit of a reference for what to do when a `tabular`(x) is _not_ the thing to use, but per the discussion in chat, my idea was actually flawed from the start. TL;DR: I'm not really sure what to do with this question. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to give a general answer, but below are some table questions that I've answered with a list (not all of which were accepted by the OP:-) It's usually possible to use a custom list layout that gives a very rigid tabular-like appearance, but with just technical advantages like easier page breaking, but sometimes having decided not to use a table, you end up deciding to use a more fluid layout using more standard list (or section heading) layout.

The comment about a longest label is a case in point. To measure the longest label you either need a multiple pass solution, either multiple runs of latex (like `longtable`)
or multiple trials within the same run (like `tabularx`) both of which are relatively easy these days (the `environ` package makes it easy to do `tabularx`-like trial runs)
but if you convince yourself that a more heading-like layout is appropriate, the issue magically goes away as the indentation of the text isn't controlled by the length of the label.

[Tables with very long texts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226249/tables-with-very-long-texts/226264#226264)

[Lots of text in one table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192728/lots-of-text-in-one-table-cell/192743#192743)

[Longtable with two column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199971/longtable-with-two-column/199998#199998)

[Best practices longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87592/best-practices-longtable/87601#87601)

[Longtable with items](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145234/longtable-with-items/203888#203888)

[parameter description with long descriptions and long lists -- possibility of page break?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135333/parameter-description-with-long-descriptions-and-long-lists-possibility-of-pa)

Comment: Thanks for answering (+1). I'll take a look at your previous answers. I think I'm at the mercy of _the community_ now to decide the fate of my more-ill-posed-than-expected question. :-)

Answer (score 4):

i have a love-hate relationship with all lists and tabulars.  none of them really
does what i want for a situation like the one described, which is exactly what one
wants for, say, a list of notation.

here's a simple approach that does require one to figure out which entry "label" is the
longest, but it breaks nicely across pages because each entry is a paragraph, and if
one does get a really long "label", it can always be packed up as a `\parbox` to be
top-aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\mylistindent
\newcommand{\mylist}[1]{\par\addvspace{2pt}
  \noindent \hangindent\mylistindent
  \makebox[\mylistindent]{\hfill #1\enspace}\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\settowidth\mylistindent{the longest\kern.5em}

\mylist{First} this is the text for the first item.
\mylist{Second} this is the text for the second item.  It is
  very long, and may require several lines.
\mylist{Another} one more here
\mylist{the longest} this one has both a long label and a
  long text.  it keeps going on, and on, and on, and on,
  and on, \ldots
\mylist{Final} one more to finish off.

\medskip
\noindent
You'll need to put in some explicit space at the end.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

you want the entries left-aligned?  just shift the `\hfill` to the beginning.

you want more (or less) space between entries?  just modify the `\addvspace`.

the kind of data that usually gets included in notation lists almost begs for
`\raggedright` (or its counterpart from `ragged2e`), so don't count out that
possibility.

everything is under your control.

Comment: I just noticed that this requires manually specifying the longest label, which is something I want to avoid. Sorry, this is my fault: I mentioned it in a comment but I should have put it in the question itself.

Comment: it's possible to add a "check for longest" routine into this method, write the result to the `.aux` file, and read it in on the next run.  as pointed out by david carlisle, this does require (at least) two runs of latex.  if the question is reopened, i'll try to add one.