# description list with long label and wrapping run into the second label, and problem with \tcbline in tcolorbox package

Tags: lists, tcolorbox, cjk

This problem is related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/280914/32004)

Since long enumerate list is not acceptable in table, we have to live with list. Ulrike Fischer provide a frame work to attack this problem with package tcolorbox. But I encountered new problems. See the following example

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,sharp corners,
        colback=white,
%       overlay={\draw[dashed] ([xshift=1.75cm]interior.north west)--([xshift=1.75cm]interior.south west);}
        ]
        \begin{description}[leftmargin=2cm,style=multiline]
            \item[long description long description] item 
            \tcbline
            \item[item 2] item
        \end{description}        
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

This outputs as follows

[image]

**Several problems with the output**

1. Since we have set the wrapping of description list label using `leftmargin=2cm,style=multiline`, if the label is long, then it will run into the second label, mess up the thing. But this wrapping is need as a format request.
2. The `\tcbline` is not at the right position. It seems that `\tcbline` only keep it eye on item content not on label. In this case, it should draw the line at a lower place, right after the first label.
3. I turn the overlay as a comment, because when I turn on this, and there is an error says  "Undefined control sequence. \end{tcolorbox}". But I really need the vertical line. It seems it is related to `breakable` option, but I can't delete the `breakable` option, because this is gonna be a long list across the page.

Comment: You have to add `enhanced` to use the `overlay` feature with `tikz` code.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Thank you so much ! works! What about other problem?

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Oh, new problem. If I use enhanced, when the table across the page, there will be no border, how to prevent the border from disappearing?

Comment: To keep the border, you can use `enhanced standard` instead of `enhanced` which opens the box visually at the breaks.

Comment: The other problems are are result of wrapping ... I cannot see how to avoid the overlapping without manual spaces.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Thank you for reply, but new problems. If I use `enhanced standard` the overlay disappear again...

Comment: That should not happen. I added a (partial) answer to show the complete code. The `overlay` works for me with that code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer which solves the `overlay` problem. Mainly, I added `enhanced standard` to the option list.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,sharp corners,
        enhanced standard,
        colback=white,
        overlay={\draw[dashed] ([xshift=1.75cm]interior.north west)--([xshift=1.75cm]interior.south west);}
        ]
        \begin{description}[leftmargin=2cm,style=multiline]
            \item[long description long description] item
            \tcbline
            \item[item 2] item
        \end{description}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarify this. I wrote the wrong way as "enhanced, standard" before